# Why does member initilizer invoke extra constructor call when moved?

Tags: c++, constructor, language-lawyer, move-semantics, move-constructor

When a member initializer is used in a class that has a move constructor the initilized member's constructor gets called when the enclosing class is moved. Why does this happen? Please provide references to the standard. I have a guess as to what's happening that I give with the example results below.

Also, in slightly different scenrio, why doesn't the member's constructor get called if the initialized member is a plain-old-data type?

Also, what are best practices concerning member initializers and move constructors?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
struct C {
    void do_stuff(){cout<<"stuff";}
    C(){cout<<"C ctor"<<endl;}
    ~C(){cout<<"C DTOR"<<endl;}
};
struct Foo {

ifdef MEMBER_INIT
    Foo() {cout<<"Foo ctor"<<endl;};
#else
    Foo() : ptr(new C) {cout<<"Foo ctor"<<endl;};
#endif

    Foo(Foo &) = delete;
    Foo & operator=(Foo &) = delete;
    Foo & operator=(Foo &&) = delete;
    Foo(Foo && rhs){cout<<"Foo MOVE ctor"<<endl; rhs.ptr.swap(this->ptr); }
    ~Foo(){cout << "Foo DTOR "; if(ptr) ptr->do_stuff(); cout<<endl; }

#ifdef MEMBER_INIT
    unique_ptr<C> ptr = make_unique<C>();
#else
    unique_ptr<C> ptr;
#endif

};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    Foo f2(move(f));
}
```

RESULTS:

```
g++ -std=c++14 x.cc && ./a.out
    C ctor
    Foo ctor
    Foo MOVE ctor
    Foo DTOR stuff
    C DTOR
    Foo DTOR

g++ -DMEMBER_INIT -std=c++14 x.cc && ./a.out
    C ctor
    Foo ctor
    C ctor
    Foo MOVE ctor
    Foo DTOR stuff
    C DTOR
    Foo DTOR stuff
    C DTOR
```

Why does using the member initializer invoke another constructor call for C?
Why does using the member initializer cause the Foo destructor to run C->do_stuff()?

My quess is that member initializers get evaluated for ALL constructor types before the actual constructor (in this case a move constructor) gets run. Is that correct?

I would specifically like references in the standard that verify or contradict my guess.

Comment: "*Why does using the member initializer invoke another constructor call for C?*" Because... that's what you told it to do. What do you think `make_unique` *does*?

Comment: Yes, however, my question asks to verify that member initializers get evaluated for move constructors. Before seeing this behavior I expected them to only be evaluated for regular constructors. To me, this is surprising behavior.

Comment: In other words, do member initilizers get evaluated for **all** constructor types? What about assignment?

Comment: One of the best practices concerning member initializers and move constructors (and not concerning member initializers and move constructors) is to write portable code. `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` is not portable code. For example, Visual C++ users cannot compile your code.

Comment: @Lotney: "*What about assignment?*" Assignment only happens to objects that have been constructed. Default member initializers, as the name suggest, are used to *initialize* a member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `MEMBER_INIT` is defined move constructor performs `ptr` initialization using in-class initializer and becomes

```
Foo(Foo && rhs): ptr{make_unique<C>()}
```

Otherwise it is default-initialized.

> **15.6.2 Initializing bases and members [class.base.init]**
>   9 In a non-delegating constructor, if a given potentially constructed subobject is not designated by a mem-initializer-id (including the case where there is no mem-initializer-list because the constructor has no ctor-initializer), then
>   …
>   the entity is initialized from its default member initializer as specified in 11.6;

Basically you forgot to actually manually initialize `ptr` field by moving:

```
Foo(Foo && rhs): ptr{::std::move(rhs.ptr)}
```